# Pyqt: How do I erase a text drawn at paintEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qpainter

I made a Roatatable Text class which inherits QWidget, and it works fine.
But when I tried to erase this text with
`label.destroy()`,
it's not disappearing.

I tried to use `QPainter.eraseRect()`, changing `painter` to `self.painter` and
executing `label.painter.eraseRect()`.
But I failed.

Here's the code:

```
class RotatedText(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, x, y, angle, text, color):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        # Setting variables...
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        # I did this because texts ain't showing if they're too far away from (0, 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.translate(self.x, self.y)
        painter.rotate(self.angle)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.color_r, self.color_g, self.color_b)))
        painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont("나눔고딕", 20))
        painter.drawText(0, 0, self.text)
        painter.end()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        label = RotatedText(50, 50, 45, "hi", (0, 0, 0))
        label.setParent(self)
        label.show()
```

(Erased other codes not related to this)

Texts drawn with `drawText()` are on a widget, so I thought destroying widget could erase the texts, too...
How do I erase it?

It's OK to replace this class with a new class inherits QLabel. It'll be lot more easy to use but I failed to make it, so I'm using this class.

p.s. Just erasing everything that has been painted is not appropriate solution for me because there are lots of texts and I want to erase just one.

Comment: Explain better please, what do you mean by *there are lots of texts*? Could you show an image to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I meant I created a lot of instance of this class by _there are lots of texts_. So erasing everything that was made with QPainter is not appropriate. (Sorry for the poor explanation, my native language isn't English)

Comment: Why do not you set `self.text = ""` and call `update()` to paint an empty text again?

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you so much! I didn't know there was an update function

Comment: `update()` calls `paintEvent()` internally :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `self.text = ""`
and calling `update()` worked.
Big Thanks to eyllanesc!

- I tried `destroy()` on other widgets, but it seems not to be 'destroyed'. Instead, `deleteLater()` worked. It worked on the widget I've made, too.